# Javascript/Jquery - Get the link of a visible image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some modals where there are some images. I also have a download button, that should download just the **shown** (the only visible) image in the modal.
I tried to make that the href link of the download button is equal to the visible image href, but it it doesn't seem to work...
[Here](https://www.provalibe.altervista.org/materia-stackoverflow.php) you can see the full page code, but the part that interests me is this one:

```html
<div id="myModal_12" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="Slide mySlides_12">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
      <img src="uploads/IMG_4946.JPG43879.jpg" class="little_image" style="width:50%;">
    </div>
    <div class="Slide mySlides_12">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
      <img src="uploads/IMG_4949.JPG21730.jpg" class="little_image" style="width:50%;">
    </div>
    <div class="Slide mySlides_12">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
      <img src="uploads/IMG_4950.JPG72501.jpg" class="little_image" style="width:50%;">
    </div>
    <!-- Next/previous controls -->
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <a onclick="downloadFunction(this)">Download this image</a>
    </div>

    <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal(12)">
                                                    <img src="/images/close.png">
                                                </span>
    <a class="prev" style=" display: block; " onclick="plusSlides(-1, 12)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" style=" display: block; " onclick="plusSlides(1, 12)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>


<script>
  function downloadFunction(linkElement) {
    var little_image = document.getElementsByClassName("little_image"); // Get all the images with that class
    var right_image = $(little_image).not(":hidden"); // Get just the visible image
    var src = right_image.src;
    linkElement.href = src; // Set the link href on the visible image src
  }
</script>
```

The JavaScript function return an "undefined" value...
Any help is very appreciated

Comment: `right_image` is a jQuery object.  jQuery objects do not expose properties or attributes directly.  You have to use `attr('src')` or `prop('src')`

Comment: `linkElement.href = $('.little_image:visible').attr('src');`

Comment: @Taplar your solution works perfectly, thank you very much. You can propose it as answer to the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the `src` attribute of an element you should use the `attr(<attribute>)` method.  Given what you are trying to do, this logic could be reduced to:

```
linkElement.href = $('.little_image:visible').attr('src');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get an attribute of element you should use attr function. In your problem you need to call like this;

```
linkElement.href = right_image.attr('src');
```

In addition, if you want to set an attribute then use .attr(attribute, value) like this:

```
right_image.attr("src", "https://www.example.com/")
```

Answer (score 1):

As Taplar has said you can use:

```js
linkElement.href = $(".little_image:visible").attr("src");
```

However, there is an issue. The jQuery function returns an array and if you added another element that fits this criteria before this element that could cause an issue. Since attr returns for the first element of that array it may not work for the proper element you wanted it to. To fix this you could write this:

```js
linkElement.href = $(".little_image:visible")[1].getAttribute("src"); // [1] the second element
```

Comment: Your code returns an error: _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined at downloadSingle_

Comment: Urel try using $(document).ready(function(){}) to make sure the DOM is ready. However, it worked fine for me when I tried it https://jsfiddle.net/mzpyLh8o/.

Comment: If you are using a very old browser like IE that could be breaking it. Also, make sure getAttribute can work. Did you try my jsfiddle?

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. But the code of Taplar seems to work correctly, i think that for me it is great

Comment: `$('.little_image:visible').eq(0).attr('src')` could also be used to get only the first element